# The current PHP SESSION is replaced after logging in another different account using another pc

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, xampp

Please be kind to me, I'm new here.

I've already search first before asking, but what I have found is that a PHP SESSION is unique per pc/unit.

By the way. I'm developing a Website using HTML, CSS, PHP, Javascript, jQuery, MS SQL SERVER and XAMPP (PHP 7.2).

**MY PROBLEM/SCENARIO**

I have two pcs and I'm testing to login 2 different users into two different pc/units. First I'm logging into PC1 then I'm logging into PC2. Upon logging in PC2 with different account, I tried to refresh the page of PC1 then upon refreshing, the SESSION is replaced. How did I know? I have tried this code:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';
```

and the result is replaced by the 2nd logged in.

For more info these are my sample codes for my sample login:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>TEST WEB APP</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>LOGIN</div>

  <br>

  <input id="usid" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">

  <button id="signin" name="signin" type="button">SIGN IN</button>

  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="sign-in.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**sign-in.js**

```
$("button#signin").click(function(){ 

    if($("#usid").val() == ""){

        alert("Fill all the required fields!")

    }else{
        var usid = $("#usid").val()
        $.post("sign-in.php",{usid:usid},function(data){ 

            if (data == 1) {
                window.location.assign("db-customer.php");
            }
            else if (data == 2){
                window.location.assign("db-sales.php");
            }
            else if (data == 3){
                window.location.assign("db-after-sales.php");
            }
            else if (data == 4){
                window.location.assign("db-manager.php");
            }
            else if (data == 5){
                window.location.assign("db-admin.php");
            }
            else{
                alert("Account does not exist!");
            }

        });
    }

});
```

**sign-in.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $conn = "";
    $serverName = "SAMPLE\MSSQLSERVER01"; 
    $connectionInfo = array( "DATABASE"=>"SAMPLE_DB");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if(isset($_POST['usid'])){

        $usid = $_POST['usid'];

        $qryCHECK = "EXEC SP_CHECK_USERS @usid = '".$usid."'";

        $rsltCHECK = sqlsrv_query($conn,$qryCHECK);

        $fetchCHECK = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rsltCHECK,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

        $roco = $fetchCHECK['roco'];

        if($roco > 0){

            $qryGET = "EXEC SP_GET_USERS @usid = '".$usid."'";

            $rsltGET = sqlsrv_query($conn, $qryGET);

            $fetchGET = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rsltGET);

            echo $fetchGET['usty'];

            $_SESSION['usid'] = $fetchGET['usid'];
            $_SESSION['usna'] = $fetchGET['usna'];
            $_SESSION['usem'] = $fetchGET['usem'];
            $_SESSION['usty'] = $fetchGET['usty'];

        }
        else{

            echo "Account does not exist!";

        }

    }
    else{
        echo "Failed";
    }

    sqlsrv_close($conn);

?>
```

**db-admin.php and db-sales.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>TEST WEB APP</title>
</head>

<body>

  <br>

  <?php
    session_start();
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';
  ?>

  <br>

  <a href='sign-out.php'>SIGN OUT</a>

</body>

</html>
```

These are my codes then just like what I've said I'm refreshing the page on PC1 then the result will be replaced by the session like the PC2 after logging into PC2.

I hope you can help me and please be kind to me.

Thanks,

Comment: use `@session_start();` at the beginning of the page and  use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in your code to show errors

Comment: what do you mean by saying "SESSION is replaced" ... replaces to what? this is happening only when logging in PC2?  you tried to login to PC1 and just refresh the page? and use session_start() as marhadbt said in the previous comment

Comment: Shushu the current session is replaced. For example in PC1 I login a user naming USER1 then while it is logged in I tried logging in to another computer using a different account for example naming USER2, so as of now i should have 2 currently different session but upon refreshing a page in PC1 the SESSION is replaced and the current user logged in in PC1 is USER2. Does this clarify your question?

Comment: Mahradbt i tried your advice but upon testing i didn't receive any output/error.